# How reach window from NWJS background script?

Tags: node-webkit, nwjs, nwjs-contexts

I am loading a background script in NWJS with the following manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "Testing background process",
    "main": "index.js",
    "bg-script" : "bg.js"
}
```

From the background script, I want to access the window, so I'm trying:

```
let win = nw.Window.get()
console.log(win)
```

But that gives the following error:

> Uncaught cannot get current window; are you in background page/node context?

How can I find the window from a background script? My goal is to listen to events in the current window.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but instead of *bg-script* use *node-main*